# How to extract mesh from a mesh object in sculpt mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

[image]

Hey guys, I am trying to sculpt a panda model and while I know how to do the basic sculpting and adding different objects for parts I am not sure how to make the eyes for the sculpt (the black parts for the panda) I saw a video somewhere where a lasso tool to extract a part of mesh and then sculpting it on the body to get that 3D effect but I am quite unsure how to do that. Any help will do! Thanks!